# Showing class not found error in intellij for gui preview

Tags: java, swing, oop, intellij-idea

[Here is picture of my error[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS0Fy.png). [It is message showing error.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6bGp.png)I have made Swing program in IntelliJ Idea but when i tried to preview it it is showing class not found error. Also in generated code in IntelliJ is showing an error.

I have tried to change JDK version but nothing is helping.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Q17 {
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JPanel info;
    private JPanel heading;
    private JPanel button;
    private JPanel answers;
    private JButton findMyAgeButton;
    private JComboBox comboBox1;
    private JComboBox comboBox2;
    private JComboBox comboBox3;
    private JTextField textField1;
    private JTextField textField2;
    private JTextField textField3;
}
```

Help me to preview my form.

Comment: If you get an error, Show the error message

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Always copy/paste error and exception output!